# Bound on $L^1$ norm of pairwise sums

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals

Just wondering if there's a nice way to bound the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^1 |\sin (2\pi mx)+\sin (2\pi nx)| \mathrm {d}x $$

More specifically, what's the best upper bound you can get? Even a universal upper bound is fine, e.g. $3/2$.

Edit: To clarify, I'm looking for a bound less than $3/\pi $. A related question is to find a sequence of measurable functions $\{f_n\} $ on $[0,1]$ such that $\int |f_n | = 1$ and for all $m,n, \, \int |f_m+f_n| \le c $ for a given $c>0. $ How small can $c $ be?

Comment: Do you want a better bound than 2?

Comment: haha yes, sorry

Comment: What are the restrictions on $m$ and $n$? Positive integers?

Comment: yes @RoryDaulton

Comment: With the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get a neat $\color{red}{1}$, despite the fact that the optimal constant (it can be computed through Fourier series) is a bit less than one, just see below.

Answer (score 3):

We have:
$$ I = 2\int_{0}^{1}\left|\sin((m+n)\pi x)\cos((m-n)\pi x)\right|\,dx $$
hence assuming $m\neq n$ the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality trivially gives:

> $$ I \leq 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}} = \color{red}{1} $$

since for any $m\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ we have:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(\pi mx)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\cos^2(\pi mx)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}. $$

---

**Edit:** The optimal constant can be deduced from computing the Fourier series of $\left|\,\sin x\,\right|$.

Over $[0,2\pi]$ we have:
$$ \left|\,\sin x\,\right| = \frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2nx)}{4n^2-1},\qquad \left|\,\cos x\,\right| = \frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n \cos(2nx)}{4n^2-1} $$
hence:

> $$ I \leq \frac{8}{\pi^2}\left(1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(4n^2-1)^2}\right)=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{4}{\pi^2}}=0.90528473\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Use $\sin p+\sin q=2\sin{(\frac{p+q}{2})}\cos{(\frac{p-q}{2})}$ so the integral becomes $$2\int_0^1|\sin{(m+n)\pi x}\cos{(m-n)\pi x}|dx$$